# jQuery - Check to see if all siblings have the same class, if so do something

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing a jquery function to check and see if all the sibling li's have a certain class of "out", if so then do something. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[My failed Codepen attempt](http://codepen.io/samyerkes/pen/nDwIE)

```
<ul>
  <h3>I'm a title</h3>
  <li class="out">Item 1</li>
  <li class="">Item 2</li>
  <li class="">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <h3>I'm a second set of people</h3>
  <li class="out">Item 1</li>
  <li class="out">Item 2</li>
  <li class="out">Item 3</li>
</ul>

$('h3').each(function() {
  if( $('h3').nextAll('li').hasClass('out')) {
    $('h3').css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

html

```
<ul>
  <li><h3>I'm a title</h3></li>
  <li class="out">Item 1</li>
  <li class="">Item 2</li>
  <li class="">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><h3>I'm a second set of people</h3></li>
  <li class="out">Item 1</li>
  <li class="out">Item 2</li>
  <li class="out">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

then

```
$('li:has(h3)').each(function() {
  if($(this).siblings(':not(.out)').length == 0){
    $(this).find('h3').css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mGkMr/)

Answer (score 1):

Yours is **invalid HTML**, so changed it to

**HTML**

```
<h3>I'm a title</h3>
<ul>
    <li class="out">Item 1</li>
    <li class="">Item 2</li>
    <li class="">Item 3</li>
</ul>
 <h3>I'm a second set of people</h3>
<ul>
    <li class="out">Item 1</li>
    <li class="out">Item 2</li>
    <li class="out">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('ul').each(function() {
  if( $(this).find('li.out').length == $(this).find('li').length) {
    $(this).prev('h3').css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/uLuSG/)

Comment: Yes, I knew it was invalid putting the h3 in the ul, but I didn't think it mattered that much. Thanks for showing me how to check the .length. That's extremely valuable.

Comment: @Moose, Its important that we should use valid HTML. You never know,  How browser will interpret invalid HTML.